# Using JSTL with JSF 1.1

Tags: java, jsf, jstl, iteration

I'm trying to use JSTL with JSF 1.1. The following code is causing me a problem:

```
<c:forEach var="key" items="${names}">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{key}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{key}"/>
    </h:column>
</c:forEach>
```

where **names** is a *String* list. Names are the key of a map contained in data displayed in the table i.e. I'm trying to do accomplish something like this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{data.fooMap[key]}"/>
```

This code is working fine outside **h:dataTable** (iteration and display of names), but when I put it inside the table nothing is displayed.

Does anyone has a clue how to fix this problem?
Is there a JSF tag that can iterate over the list inside the **h:dataTable**?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: jsp's EL and jsf's EL won't be processed at the same pass

Comment: @Jigar: actually, it are the tags, not EL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSF and JSTL doesn't run in sync as you'd expect from the coding. During view build time it's JSTL which runs from top to bottom first, the result is a pure JSF component tree without any JSTL tags. Then, during view render time it's JSF which runs from top to bottom again to produce HTML.

If the `${names}` is definied as `var` of the `<h:dataTable>` then it is simply not available when JSTL is doing its job.

You need to head to a different solution (populating dynamically in backing bean), or to adopt a 3rd party component library which allows generating dynamic columns. For example RichFaces has a [`rich:columns`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_columns.html) component which is designed for exactly this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for proposing the solution. Since I was about to start using  MyFaces Tomahawk JSF components, I've used **t:columns** which solved my problem. Thanks again!